# Is this operator between $\ell^{25}$ and $\ell^{12}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

**Problem:** Let us define $\ell^p$ as the space of sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|^p < +\infty$ with the usual norm $$\|x\|_p = \big( \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|x_n|^p \big)^{\frac 1 p}$$
Define $T:\ell^{25} \to \ell^{12}$ in the following way:
$$T(x_1,\dots,x_n, \dots) = (x_1^{2018},\dots,x_n^{2018}, \dots)$$
I am asking if the map $T$ is continuous.

**Attempt:**
Let us fix $x \in \ell^{25}$ and let us study what happens for $y \in \ell^{25}$ with $\|y-x\|_p \leq 1$. We have that $|y_n-x_n| \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and thus $|x_n^{2018}-y_n^{2018}| \leq |x_n - y_n| K$ for $K > 0$ depending only on $\|x\|_p$ which has been fixed. This is because $a^n-b^n = (a-b)p(a, b)$ where $p$ is a polynomial on $a$ and $b$.

Thus $\|Tx-Ty\|_{12}^{12} \leq K^{12} \|x-y\|_{12}^{12}$ but this does not help me to conclude because we cannot control the $\mathcal{l}^{12}$ with the $\mathcal{l}^{25}$ norm.

*Trivial remark:* the operator is not linear and thus we have no hope to prove that $T$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Wasn't this question asked recently and received quite a few votes? It may have lacked context : is that the reason for reasking? +1. The other question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4349664/non-linear-operator-from-ell25-to-ell12).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I tried to prove enough context in order to receive an answer

Comment: Thanks, Filippo, this is a very nice question, given that if it has a nice answer, one could use it as an example of working with non-linear operators in function/sequence spaces.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I haven't seen it yet. Thank you so much. The fact is that in that case $4<6$ but in our case $25>12$. The spaces are in some way inverted. If it was $T:\mathcal{l}^{12} \to \mathcal{l}^{25}$ the proof would be exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry, I just removed the post you referred to above, because I thought I'd put the wrong link, when in fact I'd put the right one. I'll just put it up , it's [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089869/continuity-of-a-function-between-lp-spaces?rq=1) @Filippo

Comment: I honestly do not understand why you write “the operator is non linear so there is no hope to prove $T$ is Lipschitz”.. there are nonlinear operators that are Lipschitz and this implies they are continuous as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $a^n-b^n =  (a - b) \ ( \ a^{n-1} \ + \ a^{n-2}b \ + \ a^{n-3}b^2 \ + \ \ldots \ + \ b^{n-1} \ )$.
Let $x \in \mathcal{l}^{25}$ be fixed and let $y \in \mathcal{l}^{25}$ be such that $\|y-x\|_{25} \leq 1$. Thus for all $n$ we have $|x_n| \leq \|x\|_{25}$ and $|y_n| \leq \|y-x\|_{25}+\|x\|_{25} \leq 1+\|x\|_{25}$.

Let us compute
$$\begin{align*}
\|Tx-Ty\|_{12}^{12}&= \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|x_n^{2018}-y_n^{2018}|^{12} \\
&= \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|(x_n - y_n) \ ( \ x_n^{2017 } \ + \ x_n^{2018-2}y_n \ + \ x_n^{2018-3}y_n^2 \ + \ \ldots \ + \ y_n^{2018-1} \ )|^{12} \\
&=  \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|(x_n - y_n) |^{12} |( \ x_n^{2017 } \ + \ x_n^{2018-2}y_n \ + \ x_n^{2018-3}y_n^2 \ + \ \ldots \ + \ y_n^{2018-1} \ )|^{12} \\
&\leq  \left( \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|(x_n - y_n)|^{12 \cdot 3} \right)^{\frac 1 3} \left( \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |(  x_n^{2017 }  +  x_n^{2018-2}y_n  +  x_n^{2018-3}y_n^2  +  \ldots  +  y_n^{2018-1} )|^{12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \right)^{\frac 2 3}
\end{align*}$$

Now $\big( \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|(x_n - y_n)|^{12 \cdot 3} \big)^{\frac 1 3}=\|x-y \|_{36}^{12} \leq \|x-y\|_{25}^{12}$.

Finally:
$$\big( \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |( \ x_n^{2017 } \ + \ x_n^{2018-2}y_n \ + \ x_n^{2018-3}y_n^2 \ + \ \ldots \ + \ y_n^{2018-1} \ )|^{12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \big)^{\frac 2 3} \leq \big( \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n|^{2017 \cdot 12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \ + \ |x_n|^{2016 \cdot 12 \cdot \frac 3 2}|y_n|^{12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \ + \ |x_n|^{2015 \cdot 12 \cdot \frac 3 2}|y_n|^{2 \cdot 12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \ + \ \ldots \ + \ |y_n|^{2017 \cdot 12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \ )|^{12 \cdot \frac 3 2} \big)^{\frac 2 3} \leq C(\|x\|_{25})$$
since $y \in B_{\mathcal{l}_{25}}(x,1)$.
Thus we found an estimate as:

$$\|Tx-Ty\|_{12} \leq \big( C(\|x\|_{25}) \big) ^{\frac{1}{12}} \|x-y\|_{25}$$

for all $y \in B_{\mathcal{l}_{25}}(x,1)$

Comment: Nice use of Holder's inequality to bump up the exponent.

Comment: Excellent work! I am happy that things worked out. +1, and I'll bookmark this one.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer thank you